# .IsEmpty returns False

Tags: ios, swift, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using the following code to check if the array is empty and then return 0 number of rows for tableview to avoid the crash. But even when the array is empty it is not returning 0 row count and enters the else part which it is not supposed to do. Hence my application crashes with an index out of range exception.

I have tried putting two checks using `count` and `isEmpty` but it still enters the else part even when the array is empty.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if HomeVC.categoryDetail.count == 0{
        return 0
    }else{
        if(HomeVC.categoryDetail.isEmpty)
        {
            return 0
        }
        else
        {
            return HomeVC.categoryDetail.count + 3 as Int
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ensure that it won't enter the else part when the array has no value.

Comment: Print `HomeVC.categoryDetail` and see what is inside it

Comment: Can you please attach the code for cellForRow?

Comment: Code seems right. Your `HomeVC.categoryDetail` is not empty. That's why it is going into else part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont. Actually you never reach `HomeVC.categoryDetail.isEmpty` because you checked `HomeVC.categoryDetail.count == 0` earlier.

**Note 1**: Generally `.isEmpty` is much more performant than getting `.count`. Because there is no need to count items when you can check only the last index.

> Count Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection. - [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection#2848969)

**Note 2**: There is no need to cast `count` to `Int`. Because it can be done automatically from `UInt` to `Int`. And count **is returning as `Int`** Already.

**Note 3**: Use `? :` for *one line two conditions* situations. It will prevent you from extra codes and undefined states.

So the code would be:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return HomeVC.categoryDetail.isEmpty ? 0 : HomeVC.categoryDetail.count + 3
}
```

**Note 4**: Try `print(HomeVC.categoryDetail)` before `return` to see what is inside when you expect to be empty and it's not.

Comment: Note 1 is not correct for an array, both properties are O(1).

Comment: @ielyamani only if the collection conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`, otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection. [Read Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection#2848969)

Comment: Doesn't Array already conform to it?!! The OP asks *"the following code to check if the array is empty"*. That part of your answer is wrong.

Comment: I can't say, because I don't see OP's *array* to check if it conforms or not. But I edit my answer a bit ti be more general for that. Thanks for your care. @ielyamani

Comment: This is not the right place to mention the difference between `.isEmpty` and `.count` for types that are not random access. See for example https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225439/49921. "Note 1" is NOT relevant to this question.

Comment: @ielyamani **THE BEST** place to mention the difference between two things in an answer is where the OP used both without knowing the difference.

Comment: For an array, there is no difference. You might as well talk about android while you're at it because it is not relevant either.